# Causal fermion systems fromm fractal geometry

Tags: noncommutative-geometry, fractals, foliations, spin-geometry

Okay, first off- I apologise if this is a stupid question. I'm mainly a very young physics guy, but this has primarily math basis. I'm trying to build a theory that is, long story short, some unification of Causal Fermion Systems and Scale Relativity. I am merely 17, and taught myself calculus at 13, able to solve the Einstein field equations by 14 and very philosophical, and very much a physicist. *However* these topics seem to be rarely mentioned together despite their connections and it's very hard to get anything but confusion from reading the various papers of each individual subject.

That said- and this likely a silly question- 
I am aware that fractals can apparently be described by spectral triples, and that manifolds with foliations can 'create' noncommutative spaces.

The questions:

But what about foliations on fractals with "non-integer dimensions"? (i.e., considering the integer dimensions separate) What would the generalization to non-commutative spaces in this case be?

Is there a way to 'get a Causal Fermion System out of a fractal geometry'?

If this is vague, I completely understand confusion and an ***explanation*** of any downvotes would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: I'm afraid this forum is not particularly suited for open-ended discussions on research directions. To get the most out of the expertise here, you'll want to formulate a specific question. "Fermions in fractal geometries" is a well-studied topic, see for example [this 1986 article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269386901073) for an entry point to the literature.